# text if a string has a word in it and display that string if it does in c#

Tags: c#, string

i want to have something like an "if" statement that tests a string for a word or a group of words.if the word(s) are in the string it displays the string on the console.

if anyone can help it would be much appreciated.

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: String.Contains or Regex

Comment: i dont know how to text a string for a word or a group of words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use the `.Contains()` method....

```
string s = "i am a string!";
bool matched = s.Contains("am");
```

Answer (score 3):

Though this is a terribly asked question; I'm going to go against my instincts and answer it.

Build a `List<string>` you want to search for:

```
private List<string> _words = new List<string> { "abc", "def", "ghi" };
```

then build a nice little extension method like this:

```
public static bool ContainsWords(this string s)
{
    return _words.Any(w => s.Contains(w));
}
```

and so now you can just say:

```
myString.ContainsWords();
```

The entire extension class might look like this:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    private List<string> _words = new List<string> { "abc", "def", "ghi" };

    public static bool ContainsWords(this string s)
    {
        return _words.Any(w => s.Contains(w));
    }

    public static bool ContainsWords(this string s, List<string> words)
    {
        return words.Any(w => s.Contains(w));
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** depending on the needs in your application, the second method is a lot more generic. It doesn't grab the list from the extensions class, but rather allows it to be injected. However, it could be that your application is so specific that the first approach is more appropriate.

Comment: Passing the list to ContainsWords would be more generic...

Comment: @Steve, yes it would, and that would be a reasonable addition. Let me add that.

Comment: Oh well, at least something useful is coming out from this question

Answer (score 0):

```
String [] words={"word1","word2","word3"};
String key="word2";
for(int i=0;i<words.Length;i++)
{
if(words[i].Contains(key))
Console.WriteLine(words[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`String.Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method like;

```
string s = "helloHellohi";
string[] array = new string[] { "hello", "Hello", "hi", "Hi", "hey", "Hey", "Hay", "hey" };

foreach (var item in array)
{
   if(s.Contains(item))
     Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Output will be;

```
hello
Hello
hi
```

Here a <kbd>[`demonstration`](http://ideone.com/Rx7RQl)</kbd>.